# Speverse Roonerisms

Tags: code-golf

A [spoonerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoonerism) is what you get when swap the beginnings of two adjacent words in a sentence. In this challenge, we'll try to find a plausible spoonerism based on one incorrect word.

So, given a list of words** and an input word that is **NOT** in the dictionary, return a string (not necessarily a dictionary word) for which the following property holds.

There exist some indices `i` and `j` such that `input_word[:i] + output_word[j:]` and `output_word[:j] + input_word[i:]` are **BOTH** in the dictionary. Here, I'm using Python notation for substrings: `word[lo:hi]` is the substring of word starting at `lo` and ending at `hi-1`. `[:hi]` is shorthand for `[0:hi]` and `[lo:]` is shorthand for `[lo:len(word)]`.

** Say, those in the `/usr/share/dict/words` provided by the `wamerican` package in Ubuntu 16.04

An example is in the title:

```
input_word = "roonerisms"
output_word = "speverse"
i, j = 1, 2
print(input_word[:i] + output_word[j:])
print(output_word[:j] + input_word[i:])
```

You can assume that everything is lowercase and the dictionary is preprocessed to contain only letters a-z and newlines. You can take the list in whatever standard format you like (eg. sorted list, set, etc. not a preprocessed lookup table) and you need only return one string, not all of them.

Comment: Can you post or link to the word list that you want used in this challenge. Not everybody runs Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @mypetlion - the word list isn't super important. I'll upload the one I have to a pastebin, though. One second...

Comment: @mypetlion - [here](https://paste.ee/p/th3Bi) is a word list that has been preprocessed to make everything lower case and removes words that contain non-letters

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>154</s> <s>161</s> <s>157</s> 155 bytes

```python
def f(s,d):L=len(s);u,v=sum((zip([w[i:]for w in d if w[:i]==s[:i]],[[w,w[:i-L]][i<L]for w in d if w.endswith(s[i:])])for i in range(L+1)),[])[0];return v+u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFRjtwgDIafm1NYWqkELc20u2@zzZ5gbkBRRYqzoU0gwhA0vXwKGXWn6gsWv39/tmG9xsm7p303OMLYkjD8fOlndC3xlyS2ntLStr/t2sos7VmNPkAG68CAHSHLs1V9TzUoIWUWVfl0UUrar5f/zR06Q9nGqaWK4opXg62GoN0btpfHL5wLqbj8rF4CxhQcbI9przXg1zIUOyUKJ5p0wJOxP@Ip@2CIcdAEebQznpsPhwT97d4F1KblHa2zjS375hhvmgeYMTKCRf9CiJMloKid0cFAhVrvdLiChsFGWHzAMmHEgBSte4PhCjjbxTp9XKkcM1ZgsRAUDCyJIkx6w4LYfMa567rm71Qyw/uz3LTyNISxzfxjDUyj9aluVEj1HzJ/fVZNs4YyRPkhpjUTspwDE2wYmOLwUFhrit8rDo48@BT/VYpPgO2fBPzsn6F/hVv9LdzRwXuHwdJCtUXArWyEpQ2t90Tpdy8YkqMJQyEdq9RRDB6SgCHp@e6kNeh5rtZ3J7o43UQBtGptmn3/Aw)

For the testing, uses the 'standard' dictionary with some tweaks (because that dictionary includes single letters, it makes for a lot of boring results).

2 bytes thx to [Jakob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44945/jakob).

Comment: @Jakob: Thx! I think that's fixed now...

Comment: @Jakob: D'oh! Forgot to trim that out, thx...